# Visual Studio .NET: How to modify label text and background color with two buttons

Tags: .net, colors, background, label

I am very new to computer programming (just started, for a class) and I am using Visual Studio .NET.

What I am trying to do is have a label, with background color and text, be modified by two buttons. When one button (let's call this "Button A") is clicked, the program will say "Yellow on Green" in which the text is yellow on a green background. When the second button (let's call this "Button B") is clicked, the program then says "Green on Yellow" in which the text is green on a yellow background.

I am able to input the label and buttons, however I am having trouble writing the code to allow what I want to happen, primarily because I have no idea what to write.

I am only familiar with "Dim", "Convert.ToInt32", and "Convert.ToDouble". Any and all help (or even a small step by step guide) would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to programming! Heres a bit of a step by step for you:

1. Drag two buttons and a label onto your form.
2. Double click the button you want to be "Green on Yellow"
3. You should be presented with the button's 'onClick' function. In there you simply need to put:

   ```
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Label1.Text = "Whatever you want the text to say"
   ```
4. Repeat for other buttons with different colours and text.

Comment: @user3200800 If you like an answer, accept it by clicking the grey check mark on the left. This would let others know that you problem is solved, and earn you (and in this case, the author of the answer) a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is not a "tell me how to do this" site.  Show us what you have tried or what is not working for you, and then we can try to help you.

But in the interest of welcoming you to the site, you should be looking into several areas:

- Try using Google to look up beginning asp.net tutorials.  Coloring the background or foreground color of a label is very basic and can probably be intuited out by looking over the properties panel of the label control in visual studio.
- How to add code to the click event of a button.
- How to import existing classes -specifically the System.Drawing namespace- which contains methods for referencing colors.

You'll want to add code to the click event of your buttons that changes the color of each label property and you'll want to be sure your button causes the page to postback or the changes will not take effect for you.

Good luck!

Comment: You guys are great, thank you! And sorry MTAdmin. TBH, I really don't know "how" to ask half of the programming questions I have because I'm so unfamiliar with the language and have trouble identifying what could be wrong.

Thank you though!